Taylor expansion gives a wrong estimate of a residue?
Consider the function $F(z) = e^{iz} / (z^2+1)^2$. To compute the residue of $F$ at $z_0=I$, one can compute the limit of the function $\frac{d}{dz} \left\{ (z-z_0)^2 \, F(z) \right\}$ as $z \to z_0$. Doing so, one indeed finds that the residue equals $-i / (2e)$.
Now, I am trying to understand why the following approach does not work. Write
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{iz} &= e^{-1}e^{i(z-i)}= e^{-1} \, \left( 1 + i(z-i) - \frac{(z-i)^2}{2} + \ldots\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
and use the fact that $(z^2+1)^2 = (z+i)^2 \, (z-i)^2$ to obtain that
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(z) &= \frac{e^{-1}}{(z+i)^2} \, \left( \frac{1}{(z-i)^2} + \frac{i}{(z-i)} - \frac{1}{2} + \ldots\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
In the vicinity of $z_0 = i$ one obtains that
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(z)&  &\approx \frac{e^{-1}}{(2i)^2} \, \left( \frac{1}{(z-i)^2} + \frac{i}{(z-i)} - \frac{1}{2} + \ldots\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
Identifying the coefficient of $(z-i)^{-1}$ suggest the wrong result that the residue at $z_0=i$ equals $-i/(4e)$.
Question: why is this approach wrong? Can one make it correct?

You should expand $1/(z+i)^2$ too around $z=i$

You cannot approximate $\dfrac{1}{(z+i)^2}$ by its value at $z=i$, that loses information about the function's behaviour near the point and leads to false conclusions.
For a simpler case, take $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z^2}$ and $g(z)=1+z$.
Clearly, $f(z)g(z)=\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{1}{z}$ has residue $1$ at $z=0$. Approximating $g(z)\approx 1$ we get $f(z)g(z)\approx \dfrac{1}{z^2}$, leading us to think that $fg$ has residue $0$ at $z=0$.
For a correct analysis, you should expand $\dfrac{1}{(z+i)^2}$ around $z=i$, which yields $$\dfrac{1}{(z+i)^2}=-\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{i}{4}(z-i)+\dfrac{3}{16}(z-i)^2+\cdots$$
Doing the product of all the Laurent expansions, one gets the correct residue of $-\dfrac{i}{2e}$.

$$ \frac{e^{iz}}{ (z^2+1)^2} = \frac{e^{iz}}{ (z-i)^2(z+i)^2}$$
To obtain the residue at $z=i$ you need to know what happens with $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(z+i)^2}$ around this pole.
$$ \frac{1}{(z+i)^2}=\frac{1}{((z-i)+2i)^2} = -\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{z-i}{2i}+1\right)^2}=-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{j}\frac{(z-i)^j}{2^ji^j}, \quad |z-i|<2$$
By the Cauchy product:
$$\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)^2} = -\frac{e^{-1}}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{-2}{j}\frac{i^{n-j}(z-i)^{n}}{2^ji^j(n-j)!} \quad |z-i|<2$$
Finally, dividing by $(z-i)^2$ and rearranging some terms:
$$\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2} = -\frac{e^{-1}}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{-2}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{2^j(n-j)!}\right) i^{n}(z-i)^{n-2}\quad 0<|z-i|<2$$
The residue is the coefficient of $(z-i)^{-1}$ ie when $n=1$
$$\operatorname{Res}(F(z),i) = -\frac{e^{-1}}{4}\left(\binom{-2}{0}- \binom{-2}{1}\frac{1}{2}\right)i  = -\frac{i}{2e} $$

Thank you for this very clear answer.
